# Можно ли выдвигать на выборах модератора кандидатуру не свою, а другого человека?

Tags: обсуждение, выборы

По сути весь вопрос в заголовке, просто стало интересно.  У меня нет конкретного кандидата, просто стало интересно можно ли так или нет?

Comment: Человек должен быть, как минимум в курсе, а если он в курсе и не против - что мешает ему выдвинуться самому?

Comment: Нет. Смысла в этом нет, если он сам не захотел

Comment: Скромность..))))

Comment: — Вы, чего, и пальцы за меня загибать будете?
 — Ага!  (с) Вовка в Тридевятом царстве

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ты меня заставил мульт пересмотреть, сто лет не смотрел его, но в детстве любил))))))))))))))))))))))) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DcsMksINWM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Выдвигать кого–либо отличного от себя кандидатом в модераторы сообщества нельзя. Модератор сообщества — это абсолютно добровольная позиция, от которой можно отказаться в любой момент. По сути, все модераторы сообщества — волонтеры, люди, кому не безразлична судьба сообщества. Если человек хочет менять общество, он/она должен самостоятельно об этом заявить выдвинув свою кандидатуру.

Comment: В случае отказа — он/она теряет ромб и не может получить его назад, кроме как в результате последующих выборов? Или можно передумать передумывать. А может быть при отнимании ромба на участнике/участнице ставится модераторский крест?

Comment: Точно, что получить просто так назад нельзя. Можно ли выдвигаться еще раз — вопрос, который рассматривается в индивидуальном порядке. Одно дело, к примеру, сложности на работе, другое — лень.