# Смысл уведомления о выборах

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

Рассмотрим уведомление о выборах:

> [image: скриншот уведомления]

> Выдвигайте кандидатов на выборы модераторов сообщества Stack Overflow на русском 2017!

Оно означает что-то странное, так как выдвигать **других** участников на роль модератора [нельзя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6058/227016). Предлагается выбрать новый вариант перевода, голосуйте за понравившийся вариант или предлагайте свой.

Comment: или хотя бы `выдвигайте кандидатуру`

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да, тоже хороший вариант

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тут имеет место быть проблема перевода. [Оригинальная строка](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263189?key=581e657f7d0630a485d6590d6e12168e) выглядит так:

> The $siteName$ $electionYear$ community moderator election is underway — nominations now being accepted.

Я планирую исправить следующим образом:

> Начались выборы модератора $siteName$ $electionYear$ — принимаются заявки от кандидатов.

Замечания и предложения можете высказать в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо. Может добавить ещё три ответа для трёх вариантов из вопроса и голосованием выбрать лучший вариант?

Comment: @diraria а стоит ли затягивать? Лучшее — враг хорошего. Пока выберем, выборы закончатся.

Comment: @diraria Конечно можете добавить ещё три ответа! Голосование, демократия -- это очень хорошо, главное помнить, что у нас до/после/вместо выборов случается локализаторский произвол )

Comment: @alexolut, просто мне больше нравится вариант `Участвуйте в выборах модератора сообщества Stack Overflow на русском 2017!`. Вы ведь можете сейчас перевести как вы предложили, а после голосования, возможно, изменить

Answer (score 2):

> Участвуйте в выборах модераторов сообщества Stack Overflow на русском 2017!

Answer (score -1):

> Выдвигайте кандидатуру на роль модератора сообщества Stack Overflow на русском 2017!

Answer (score -1):

> Выдвигайтесь на роль модератора сообщества Stack Overflow на русском 2017!